# JPA Assign a seat only if not already assigned

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let us say we have a User entity and Seat entity. User can pick a Seat only if the Seat has not been picked by someone else.

Here is the User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name='user')
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name='user_id')
    private Long userId;

    @Column
    @OneToOne()
    private Seat assignedSeat;

}
```

Here is the Seat class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name='seat')
public class Seat{
    @Id
    @Column(name='seat_id')
    private Long seatId;

    @Column
    private User assignedUser;

}
```

**Question**:
How can we assign a seat `Only If` the seat has not been assigned previously?

**Background**:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html

I understand that this is a OneToOne mapping. But, I am unable to find out how we can ensure atomicity. That is, assign `only if` the seat is already assigned.

Comment: Perhaps the field `assignedUser` should be a `User` type (instead of `Seat` type), and perhaps that 1-1 should be BIDIRECTIONAL, and hence have `mappedBy` ...

Comment: You are right. I updated the type of assignedUser to User. So, Seat should have mappedBy? Also, how are we supposed to make sure only one User is assigned? If two people are assigning the same seat, how do we make sure only one user can assign the seat.

Comment: In the database only 1 `User` can be assigned to the `Seat` at any time. If the `Seat` is already assigned then you enforce that in your GUI and don't allow reassignment.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly?  Two threads can conflict and the last will win when choosing a seat unless you use some form of locking. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Locking/Optimistic_Locking

Comment: atomicyty has not too much with entities declaration. All thing should be run in Transaction or @Transactional (and choose optimistic or pessimist is important)